# Alter file path based on cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A short explanation; I have a large amount of reports in one folder, and they are all formatted the exact same way every time, except for the date in the file name (ex. Out of Stock Report WE 04.20.16.xlsx). In the workbook where I have my formula, I'm referencing a cell that has a date in it, and then using that date (DT$3 reference is a date) as an input for the last part of the file path, so that it goes to the correct file and looks up the file. I don't need any actual index/match or lookup formula, because these reports are all formatted the exact same way, so the needed value is always in the same cell on the same worksheet. Here is my formula that I'm getting a #REF error on:

```
='\\dhqshareddata\data\Supply_Chain\Planning\Strategic Planning - Forecasting\Out of Stock\All Reports\[Out of Stock Report WE "&TEXT(DT$3, ("MM.DD.YY"))&".xlsx]Category Report'!$C$5
```

This should be simple but I can't get it to work. Additionally, an indirect function won't do me any good because I'll have to open every single report and copy/paste values, for hundreds of reports.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the entire path of the document, where you start with `\\dhqsharedata`.

Comment: Data is likely stored on a server and that is a valid way to reference it.  Although the quotations don't match and I'm not sure you can do this without indirect or outside tools.  A macro should be relatively trivial to hardcode the dates in based on another cell.

Comment: gtwebb is correct with one minor addition.   While you would need to use the indirect function,  even that would not work, unless the file referenced was already linked in the workbook.   VBA is definitely the way to go.